# $f$ is a monotone increasing, but not necessarily continuous, on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $A$ is compact. Is $f$ always has a maximum on $A$?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, maximum-principle

Call a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ nondecreasing if $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $x \geq y$ implies $f(x) \geq f(y)$. Suppose $f$ is a nondecreasing, but not necessarily continuous, function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact. Show that if $n = 1$, $f$ always has a maximum on $D$. Show also that if $n > 1$, this need no longer be the case.

I'm stucked at second afirmative. How to get a nondecreasing function ($f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$), with compact domain and show that there is not maximum to it?

Any thoghts would be appreciated.
Tks

Comment: What is $\leq$ in $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: Indeed, I've been think about, maybe, can i show that $\geq$ is not defined at $\mathbb{R}^n$. So, i can't mantain the afirmative. Is it right?

Comment: Coordinatewise, so $(1,2) \le (2,3)$ etc.

Comment: You can *define* it on $\Bbb R^n$, but you'd have to tell us what you mean.  You might decide that some elements are incomparable, which is fine.

Comment: The definition you write misses something essential...

Comment: This is an execirse from Sundaram(1996), that i'm trying.

Comment: Then check your textbook for a definition of $\leq$

Comment: Sundaram defines on page 3 that indeed the product order of the usual order on $\mathbf R$ is the one he uses, that is 
$$ x \le y :\iff \forall i: x_i \le y_i $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider the set
$$
A = \{(t,-t) \in \Bbb R^2: t \in [0,1]\}
$$
note that any function on $A$ is, by definition, non-decreasing.

Comment: Why is $(1,-1) \geq (0.5,-0.5)$, for any function?

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense as stated.  It sounds like you mean to ask "why is $f(1,-1) \geq f(0.5,-0.5)$ for any function $f$".  Clearly, this will not be the case for every function.  However, why do **you** think that we would need this to be true?

Comment: Note in particular that $(1,-1) \not \geq (0.5,-0.5)$

Comment: Yes, but is there a function on $A$ that is non-decreasing and does not have a maximum?

Comment: @shmiggens all you need to do here is come up with **any** (not necessarily continuous) function that does not have a maximum, since every function on $A$ will be non-decreasing. For example, you can take
$$
f(t,-t) = \begin{cases}
1/t & t \neq 0\\
0 & t=0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: That function decreases as t increases, past the point (0,0).

Comment: @shmiggens why does that matter?

Comment: Because the OP required that f be nondecreasing over the entire compact set.

Comment: @shmiggens take a closer look at what “non decreasing” means in this context

Answer (score 0):

So if you define $f(x) = -\infty, x \leq b$ and $f(x) = 1/(x-b),b < x < a$ and $f(x) = + \infty, x \geq a$ then $f$ is increasing on $(b,a)$ but does not attain a finite maximum.

Comment: That's not a map into $\mathbb R$. OP specified $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$, right?

Comment: @MPW, yes. $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.